# How to delete the rows with three same data columns and one different data column

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a table `"MARK_TABLE"` as below.

How can I delete the rows with same `"STUDENT"`, `"COURSE"` and `"SCORE"` values?

```
| ID | STUDENT | COURSE | SCORE |
|----|---------|--------|-------|
| 1  |    1    |    1   |  60   |
| 3  |    1    |    2   |  81   |
| 4  |    1    |    3   |  81   |
| 9  |    2    |    1   |  80   |
| 10 |    1    |    1   |  60   |
| 11 |    2    |    1   |  80   |
```

Now I already filtered the data I want to KEEP, but without the `"ID"`...

```
SELECT student, course, score FROM mark_table
INTERSECT
SELECT student, course, score FROM mark_table
```

The output:

```
| STUDENT | COURSE | SCORE |
|---------|--------|-------|
|    1    |    1   |  60   |
|    1    |    2   |  81   |
|    1    |    3   |  81   |
|    2    |    1   |  80   |
```

Comment: An easy way would be to select the data you want to keep into a temporary table, purge the source table, then reinsert the temporary table data into the source table.

Comment: But I don't know how to select the data with the `"ID"`. Once I select the `"ID'`, the result becomes different. And that's not what I want.

Comment: How about `SELECT STUDENT, COURSE, SCORE, MAX(ID) FROM MARK_TABLE GROUP BY STUDENT, COURSE, SCORE` to do that?

Comment: This time is works. Now I need to figurt out how to delete the rows which It's not in this output...

Comment: Tejash's Answer does that to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following query to delete the desired rows:

```
DELETE FROM MARK_TABLE M
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            MARK_TABLE M_IN
        WHERE
            M.STUDENT = M_IN.STUDENT
            AND M.COURSE = M_IN.COURSE
            AND M.SCORE = M_IN.SCORE
            AND M.ID < M_IN.ID
    )
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ee7d8e0d89626e0f51e75d7e021093a)

Cheers!!

Comment: Neat trick with using the id ordering to decide which to keep.

Comment: Why `"SELECT 1"`? What does `"1"` mean?

Comment: @Nicole the 1 is irrelevant in his example, it's a standin for "literally any record". The query operates in a way that says "If multiple records exist for a student, score, course touple, delete any record that does not have the highest ID of all records with that touple"

Comment: So can I use a random number to stand for "literally any record"? Or I can only use `"1"`?

Comment: You can use even `NULL` instead of `"1"`. `Select clause` is irrelevant in the query

Answer (score 0):

use `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct student, course, score FROM mark_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
select row_number() over (partition by student,course,score order by score) 
rn,student,course,score from mark_table
) t
where rn=1
```

Comment: This would fail for records that have a student taking the same course twice with different scores, while OP notes they want to only filter records where all 3 match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't just want to select the unique data you want to keep (you mention you've already done this), you can proceed as follows:

1. Create a temporary table to hold the data you want to keep
2. Insert the data you want to keep into the temporary table
3. Empty the source table
4. Re-Insert the data you want to keep into the source table.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE with RowNumber

```
create table #MARK_TABLE (ID int, STUDENT  int, COURSE  int, SCORE  int)
insert into #MARK_TABLE 
values 
(1,1,1,60),
(3,1,2,81),
(4,1,3,81),
(9,2,1,80),
(10,1,1,60),
(11,2,1,80)

;with cteDeleteID as(
Select id, row_number() over (partition by student,course,score order by score) [row_number]  from #MARK_TABLE
)
delete from #MARK_TABLE where id in
(
 select id from cteDeleteID where [row_number] != 1
)

select * from #MARK_TABLE
drop table #MARK_TABLE
```